# Sharepoint Blog and Articles

Tags: 2007

Can any body please give me link of good blog or site for sharepoint where daily added good article for sharepoint.

Comment: if you answer here, please remember to mark your answer community wiki!

Answer (score 3):

You could try [NothingButSharePoint / EndUserSharePoint.com)](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com)

Answer (score 3):

Planet SharePoint has a feed with 200+ active blogs providing some great content.
http://www.planetsharepoint.org/

Answer (score 1):

Go to [www.sharepoint2010blogger.com](http://www.sharepoint2010blogger.com), At least 10-20 Posts weekly.

Comment: It's redirecting to http://ww35.sharepoint2010blogger.com/ which is just a parked domain.

Answer (score 0):

I use a newsreader and every time I see a good SharePoint blog (like the ones listed above) I subscribe to that blogs RSS feed.  If I see something that I want to bookmark or that is worthy of sharing, I share it on my friendfeed at http://www.friendfeed.com/therobman.  There are others who do the same thing.  If you suscribe to one of our feeds that is a good source of info.  To put it in perspective, my reader picks up 100-120 articles per day (not all SharePoint related) and I share on average 3-5 daily.

Some other sites that I find useful are [cmswire.com](http://cmswire.com) (frequent posts about SharePoint, related products and competitive products) and [codeproject.com](http://codeproject.com) (has some SharePoint related articles and sample code from time-to-time).

For news, go to bing.com's news tab and search on SharePoint.  Then click the "News Alerts" link and subscribe to it.  You'll receive a daily email with all of the places SharePoint showed up in the news that day.

Answer (score 0):

I visit this site http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/featured_sharepoint_blogs/default.aspx

Hope this helps